# How to disable Bluetooth power saving?

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, bluetooth

I've been using a Bluetooth keyboard with Ubuntu for years now. To begin with it was quite tricky to get it to pair, but for the last several releases it's been rock solid.

After updating to 20.04 (from 19.10) it still works great, but it has acquired a new feature in which the keyboard goes to sleep if I don't type anything for a while. I presume this is deliberate and meant to be an improvement, and it reconnects just fine when I do press a key, but it takes a few seconds and drops any key presses in the meantime, so it's annoying.

How can I go back to the old always-connected mode, please?

Comment: Are you using any USB Bluetooth adapter? If yes, please mention the name and model of it in the question.

Comment: No adapter; just the built-in bluetooth of my machine, although lshw does list it as a USB device. The vendor is Intel. If there are other useful details I don't recognise them.

Comment: So I guess you're having a laptop. If yes, mention the name and model of laptop.

Comment: Dell Precision 7710.

Comment: Could you verify that tlp is on the system?

Comment: also the contents of /etc/modprobe.d/99-local.conf

Comment: TLP is not installed.

Comment: There is no /etc/modprobe.d/99-local.conf on this system.

Comment: Hi, did you happen to solve the issue? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this...

The comment in /etc/bluetooth/input.conf says it should already default to '0' so this shouldn't be needed, but explicitly setting IdleTimeout to 0 like this seems to have worked for me, I am using Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo sed -i 's/#IdleTimeout=30/IdleTimeout=0/g' /etc/bluetooth/input.conf
```

Comment: I've set this, but there's no obvious difference. :-(

Comment: I also did this, but did't work

Comment: IdleTimeout value defaults to 0. Hence, this is a misleading answer.

Answer (score 2):

After I searched, I changed the configuration items in grub, which almost solved the problem. Although I feel that this method is not very elegant, I directly modify the configuration of the kernel.

Change the `/etc/default/grub` file and add the following line
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="usbcore.autosuspend=-1"`

Update grub after modification

```bash
# grub-update
```

If there is no grub-update command, such as opensuse, use the following command

```bash
# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Restart the system after modification

```bash
# reboot
```

After restarting the system, check to see if the changes take effect

```bash
# cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
-1
```

Answer (score -4):

just go on settings power and disable the button in which comp. can save power by disabling bluetooth

.[image]

in my case it is on just disable it youcan take help from above

Comment: This will turn off the bluetooth entirely. He wants to disable the power saving feature of bluetooth, not the bluetoot itself.

Comment: i think this feature disable the devices if they are not in use in long period of time

Comment: I turned that off and bluetooth was disabled immediately. The label does seem misleading; I had assumed that this was some kind of smart feature also.

Comment: I was unable to control my computer after this.